# Macro not dividing as it should – Wrong Output

Tags: excel, vba, divide

I have a macro that isn’t producing the output it should be.  In my sample Excel sheet below, the code divides the cell amount in `D30` into 10 different cells equally up to 12.00 after 12.00, the excess amount is to go to the cell using the first number of the two in cell B30 (1 in this example). The correct output is given in the `JPEG` sample. In the sample sheet below, see the expected result to see what the current output is producing.

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vttPG.jpg) for the Excel image.

```
Sub DIVIDE()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim pair As Variant, accumulator As Variant
Dim findFifteen As Double
Dim remainder As Long, found As Long

found = 1

For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
If Right(pair, 2) = 15 Then
    If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12 Then
        findFifteen = pair.Offset(0, 2) / 10
        remainder = 0
    Else
        findFifteen = 1
        remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2) Mod 10
    End If

    For Each accumulator In Range("A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40")
        If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1)) Then
            accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + remainder
        End If
        accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + findFifteen
    Next accumulator
    End If
Next pair

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The macro is working exactly as your have programmed it.  Its internal logic is wrong, but it's not its fault.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your code does, but try the below. It gives me your expected output.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DivideSomeStuff()

    Dim pair As Range, accumulator As Range
    Dim findFifteen As Double
    Dim remainder As Long

    For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")
        If Right(pair, 2) = 15 Then
            If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12 Then
                remainder = 0
            Else
                remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2) Mod 12
            End If

            findFifteen = (pair.Offset(0, 2) - remainder) / 10

            For Each accumulator In Range("A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40")
                If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1)) Then
                    accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + remainder
                End If
                accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + findFifteen
            Next accumulator
        End If
    Next pair

End Sub
```

You should probably test with other values in cell `D30` to see if the output is still correct/as expected.

---

I still don't know what your code does, but if you change the cells `B30`, `F30` and `J30` on your sheet to end with 7 (e.g. some text like `"1-7"`) and change `NUMBER_TO_CHANGE` to the same value (7 in this case), then I think the code below will give expected output.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DivideSomeStuff()
    Const NUMBER_TO_CHANGE As Long = 7 ' Change this as needed

    Dim remainder As Long
    Dim pair As Range
    For Each pair In Range("B30, F30, J30")

        If Right(pair, Len(CStr(NUMBER_TO_CHANGE))) = NUMBER_TO_CHANGE Then
            If pair.Offset(0, 2) <= 12 Then
                remainder = 0
            Else
                remainder = pair.Offset(0, 2) Mod 12
            End If

            Dim findFifteen As Double
            findFifteen = (pair.Offset(0, 2) - remainder) / 10

            Dim accumulator As Range
            For Each accumulator In Range("A36, D36, G36, J36, M36, A40, D40, G40, J40, M40")
                If accumulator.Offset(-1, 0) = Val(Left(pair, InStr(pair, "-") - 1)) Then
                    accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + remainder
                End If
                accumulator.Value = accumulator.Value + findFifteen
            Next accumulator
        End If

    Next pair
End Sub
```

[image: Code's output]

Comment: Hi, a quick note to say a big Thank-You. You did what many could not solve. Awesome.

Comment: I just finished doing some extensive testing. with your changes when the macro divides by 10 (12.00 is the max, see above) it stops working after 24.00 is entered. Also, and this is crazy, when I change the cell output locations I get a different output and I checked all the cells have the same format. Have you ever come across such a thing? I still think you're great.

Comment: @NANCYSKYES I changed the `Mod 10` to `Mod 12` (to get expected output), so if you put `24` in cell `D30`, then `remainder` will be 0 and `findFifteen` will be `24/10`, meaning you should have `2.4` added to every `accumulator` range. Are you saying that you aren't getting this behaviour, or are you saying this is not expected/wanted behaviour? Moving the output locations shouldn't affect the output, provided you also move the labels (1, 2, 3, ...) above the  `accumulator` ranges and you change the code to reflect the change in locations.

Comment: I didn’t know about moving the labels and when I do that the output goes to the coded cells as it should.

Comment: The very last issue, and it does it now but not the way I need it to. I need the code to limit the output amount to 1.20 in each of the accumulators and any amount over 12.00 write that output to the cell using the first number of the two numbers, best to see my Excel sample that I uploaded to really be clear.  SEE NEXT NOTE

Comment: The sample output in my Excel sheet the code divides the cell amount in cell D30 (20.00) into 10 different cells equally up to 12.00  (or 1.20) and after 12.00 the excess amount is to go to the cell using the first number of the two in cell B30 (1 in this example) and adds it to any existing amount in the output cell.

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: i got it, finally. Your the best!!

Comment: @NANCYSKYES, sorry, been at work, good to know you figured it out

Comment: Hi, In January you kindly helped me with the above code and it works great, by the way. I wanted to change the following line to 7 from 15 it currently uses but the code does nothing (did a step Into and it just does not see the 7 in the cell) and I just can't figure out why.  If Right(pair, 2) = 15 is the line I change. Then the thing is if I change it to 11/12/13/14 it works fine but if I use any single digit it's no good. I'm not sure if you have time these days but if you do I sure appreciate any help suggestions as to why it would do this. Thanks so much.

Comment: @NANCYSKYES, I think you're meant to ask a new question in these sorts of situations. But I've edited my answer to include a second bit of code. Try the second bit, if you want. (It's meant to be more dynamic.)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your reply and the additional code. I’ve tested it and there are no errors but it does nothing. So I thought I would trying to change the cell format from text to general with no affect. I then tried a step through and it does the same thing as the previous code it goes down to “If Right(pair, Len...” line and then down to “End if”, “next pair” and then back to “ If Right(pair, Len...”. It just doesn’t see the seven and I don’t know why. Very frustrating.

Comment: A further note: the set of numbers could be 1-7 or 7-7 or 10-7 etc. I'm sure you can see this but if it helps. Thanks again.

Comment: @NANCYSKYES, check two things. 1. Ensure that the sets of numbers are in the correct cells (`B30`, `F30`, `J30`) -- and 2. Ensure that the values in `B30`, `F30` and `J30` are strings. If you enter `1-7` directly into a cell, Excel might try to helpful and auto-convert it to a date -- in which case the `IF` condition will never be true. To get around this, you can enter `="1-7"` or `'1-7` (that's an apostrophe at the start). Either way is okay and gets Excel to treat the value as text/literal string. I've edited my post to include a short GIF showing what the code gives me on my machine.

Comment: If it doesn't help or the output (in the GIF) is not correct, please ask a new question. My understanding is that the comments section on this website is not meant for extended conversation.

Comment: Last note. Had some computer issues and that was the problem not your code. Your code works perfectly.  I hope I didn’t get you in trouble with this follow up.  I really appreciate it. Thank-you so much. Not sure if you can help but I just posted another problem regarding a match issue. It’s titled Mismatch and Match issue.